# Function $F(n)=n+n$ is not $\Delta_0$

Tags: logic, set-theory

Define $F(n)=n+n$, for $n<\omega$, and $F(n)=0$, for $n\not\in\omega$. I have to show that this is not a $\Delta_0$-function but it's the composition of two $\Delta_0$-functions.

I have one hint; i have to show that $\{n<\omega\mid n\text{ is even}\}$, is not first order definable in $\langle\omega,<\rangle$, i have done that, after that i don't know how to proceed. I was thinking that $F=g\circ id$, where $id$ is the identity function, and $g(n)=2n$, but i don't know if the last one is a $\Delta_0$-function; in fact i think $g$ is $\Delta_1$.

Comment: Actually, your $g$ is exactly the same as $F$, so it can't be $\Delta_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, if $m=F(n)$ were $\Delta_0$, then every quantified variable would range in the transitive closure of $n$ and $m$; that is, all quantifiers would range over natural numbers. This would give you a first order definition of $F$ on the structure $(\omega,\in)=(\omega,<)$.

To express $F$ as a composition of two $\Delta_0$ functions, one must necessarily go *outside* the natural numbers. This means that the range or the domain of some of those functions must not be included in $\omega$. (Otherwise, both definitions would be actually first order definitions on $(\omega,<)$)

I'll start by giving you a hint. How to count up to $2n$ with just $n$ fingers? Use each finger twice! More of a concrete help, one of the functions should work like this (hover to see the idea):

> $ n\mapsto \{\{0,n\},\{1,n+1\},\dots,\{n-1,2n-1\}\}$

This can be done in a $\Delta_0$ way.

Comment: You can actually count to $2^n$ on $n$ fingers... :-P

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf I'm really grateful! Still struggling, but you really cleared it up; now is obvious the nature of the functions!

Comment: @AsafKaragila You can, with a strict discipline and very independent tendons... Human anatomy makes it very difficult to do all of 2, 8, 23, and 29 (depending on how you code them).

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: I am not sure how to count to $32$ on one hand. There are only $32$ subsets of fingers and $\{0, 1, \ldots, 32\}$ has $33$ elements. But it's definitely possible to count to $2^{n}-1$, at least with my tendons.

Comment: @Carl: You have five fingers, and $2^5=32$. And $\{0,\ldots,31\}$ is exactly $32$, so you can count *to* $32$.

Comment: With a little more effort I can count to $3^5-1$, since a finger can be up, down, or curled under.